# CSS no hover on overflow

Tags: css, hover, overflow

Let's say I have an html structure like so

```html
<a><span></span></a>
```

And I have the following style sheet

```css
a {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:block;
}
a:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    background:blue;
}
```

When I put my mouse at coordinates `5px`,`5px`, then we see a blue square that is `100px` by `100px`, which is great.  Now I want to put my mouse at coordinates `50px`,`50px` and NOT SHOW the large blue square.  Is there a way I can achieve this with just css?

In otherwords, i only want to see a `100px` by 100px blue box if my mouse xcoordinate is less than or equal to `10px` and ycoordinate is less than or equal to `10px`.

Comment: No problems here: http://jsfiddle.net/LVcS2/1/

Comment: i'm in chrome, when i put my mouse at coordintes 50px,50px, the box showed up.  it shoudl NOT show up. The only time the box shoudl show up is if my mouse has xposition <= 10px and yposition <= 10px

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working like this.

```
a {position:relative; width:10px; height:10px; display:block;}

span {display:none;}

a:hover span {position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; display:block; background:blue;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LVcS2/3/

Comment: This comes close, too, but doesn't have the blue box showing initially.

Comment: ok one more issue.  When i move mouse to 5px,5px, blue box opens up.  Then i moe mouse mouse 10px to the right, so that the coordinates are now 15px,5px, the blue box doesn't disappear the way i need it too.  I want the hit area for hover state to tbe ALWAYS from 0,0 to 10px,10px

Answer (score 0):

With an additional element you can get close. The problem is that the parent element (a) stretches to contain its child, if not visually, from the browser's perspective.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/LVcS2/2/

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
a {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:block;
    background:red;
}
span {
    display:block;
    background:blue;
}
a:hover span {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

<div>
    <a><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: ok one more issue. When i move mouse to 5px,5px, blue box opens up. Then i moe mouse mouse 10px to the right, so that the coordinates are now 15px,5px, the blue box doesn't disappear the way i need it too. I want the hit area for hover state to tbe ALWAYS from 0,0 to 10px,10px

Comment: Yup. That's as close as I could come with the time I had to spend. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just shrink the blue square (`<span>`) to 49x49 (or any size less than 50x50) until `a` is `:hover`:

```
a{
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0.5;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:block;
}
a:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
a:hover span{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
span{
    position:absolute;    
    width:49px;
    height:49px;
    display:block;
    background:blue;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LVcS2/4/

I changed the opacity of `a` to `0.5` for demo purposes.

Comment: ok one more issue. When i move mouse to 5px,5px, blue box opens up. Then i moe mouse mouse 10px to the right, so that the coordinates are now 15px,5px, the blue box doesn't disappear the way i need it too. I want the hit area for hover state to tbe ALWAYS from 0,0 to 10px,10px

Comment: Can't do that with pure CSS.